# Image on hover inside table not showing full image size

Tags: html, css, hover

HTML Table code:

```
<tr class="tr2">
<td class="td-center addonstitle">Addon Title</td>
<td class="td-center addonsdescription">Description</td>
<td class="td-center addonsauthor">Author</td>
<td class="td-center addonsscreenshot"><div class="hover_img"><a href="#">Show Image<span><img src="imagelink" alt="image"></a></div></td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
.hover_img a { 
position:relative; 
}

.hover_img a span { 
position:absolute; 
display:none; 
z-index:99; 
}

.hover_img a:hover span { 
display:block; 
}
```

Currently the image shows when you hover over the 'show image' link but its reduced to the size of the table (so pretty much hidden) however I want it to show the full image size when you hover over 'show image'.

I have tried setting a width/height & overflow: visible to the a:hover span CSS but the image continues to only show at the size under the table. The problem shown here: https://i.imgur.com/YxK0Npb  (red circled section) (original image for the hover: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Sf0.jpg) - it should show the full image sSKurPk when hovering.. not the small current shown part.

EDIT: Had to remove the link in the HTML code - "imagelink" links to https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Sf0.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Is there something like?

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

This could prevents the overflow / fullsize of the image.

Comment: Hey the only img CSS code loaded is the following: https://i.imgur.com/bbOs9de.png

Comment: Its difficult to answer and find a solution for this problem because we don't know the whole code/style.